Using var from a call statement in multiple models (dbt)
I am using a call statement() in order to save query results to a variable an then use it as a value in other queries.
This is the way I announce it:

{%- call statement('call_test', fetch_result=True) -%}

    select col_1 ,
    col_2 
    
    from {{ ref('mrr_dwh__my_dim') }}
    where col_1 = 'US'
        
{%- endcall -%}


{%- set my_var = load_result('call_test')['data'][0][0] -%}

select {{ my_var }}

And indeed if I compile this single model it works and the {{ my_var }} is returend correctly.
But then I try to use the same var on another model (query) without calling the statement again, like this:
{%- set my_var = load_result('call_test')['data'][0][0] -%}

select  {{my_var}}

But I get None. This variable is again undefined.
Is there a way to call statement and set the var one time in the beginning of an ETL process, and then use it on other models in Downstream?
Thank you.

I don't think there's a way to persist the variable into dbt's context so that it's available in multiple places. Further, dbt would have no idea of the precedence in that case (what if model 2 is run before model 1 because there's no information on which one goes before which)?
An alternative could be using a model to be referenced downstream (if your use case is like the example you shared).
Or turn this into a macro that you can call multiple times (and, yes, execute it against the dwh everytime you run it, but dwh should cache it).

In dbt, the scope of variables set using set and the results loaded using load_result() is limited to the compilation context of a single model. This means that when you define a variable in one model using results from a statement block, that variable's value is not globally available to other models in your dbt project. Each model in dbt is compiled into its own standalone SQL file, which is then executed independently by the database.
Therefore, I see three options here:

you enable the full statement block in all the models where you need to use the values from load_result('call_test')['data']
you create a macro with the statement block, and call it in all the needed models
you create a separate model that gathers the values of load_result('call_test')['data'], and then use some macro like dbt_utils.get_column_values to iterate over the values in other models.


Thanks. I will extend the use-case: My final goal is to use the value in it's raw level without a query.
If Im not mistaken, if I will use a macro instead, it will just perform the query again.
Let's say I use a date variable, and then use it in a query in a form of "where date = {{my_var}} - if my var is a macro the query will be executed inside this where clause, and I am looking for a solution that will ingest the value of the date directly

but to get the values, you need to query the {{ ref('mrr_dwh__my_dim') }} model, right?

Yes, but not in the same job
